# Need help for an unknown 7-bit checksum

Tags: crc

i am struggling since a long time to determine the checksum of the following sequences.

I have two examples.

Ex1: Have the same checksum and one have a payload incrementation  by 0x0A
at the same position (Byte 8).

Ex2: This one have the same checksum (9.byte).

I am sure this are the checksum and is always 1 Byte.
What I noticed is that the values of checksum is not bigger than 0x7F.
I have many expamples but i see that it never grows up to 0x80.
It can also not 0xFF because 0xFF marks the sequenze as the end.

**Example with paylod increment of 0x0A on the 8.Byte.**
01: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   00  29
02: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   0A  19
03: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   14  49
04: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   1E  79
05: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   28  4A
06: ED  0   1   0   1   0   0   32  44

**This examples has the same checksum (0x53):**
01: E4  09  01  02  26  50  00  53
02: E4  10  01  01  00  0F  00  53
03: E4  14  01  09  42  09  41  53
04: E4  15  01  14  48  08  03  53
05: E4  01  02  21  02  50  00  53
05: E4  01  02  22  22  52  00  53
06: E4  01  02  22  31  05  00  53
07: E4  02  02  02  10  0D  05  53

I have tested various algorythms.
Fletcher, Adler32, BSD 8Bit are one of them.
Xor8 an some tests with shiftet bits and various modulus.
I have xored the values but nothing of worth comes out.
Reveng gave me some results but not for all sequences.
I am also sure that it is not a CRC but only a simple checksum.

I have read many threads if there was a hint how i can reverse the checksum.
But i see nothing wich handles 7bit. I also look at the bits but i dont know on how to begin.

I see some participations but dont see the relation.
In the first block I see that the checksum is ending in 0x09. (Set 1 - 4)
If the payload increases by 0x0A the checksum also increments by 0x30 (Set 2-4)
until a specific point (Set 5).

I am sure it is very simple. In german i would say "ich sehe den Wald vor lauter Bäumem nicht".
Don't know the correct translation in english. ;-)

It would very appreciate if someone can point me the right direction.

With best regards
Chris

Edit:
- replaced the word "crc" in the text by "checksum" for better understanding.
  Tnx to JimmyB for the hint.

Comment: your expression would be "I cannot see the wood for the trees" in English.

Comment: I find it confusing that you're referring to the unknown checksum as "CRC" throughout your question.

Comment: You are right. I have not considered when writing.

I think in this case at first it makes no difference 
but I already know that a crc is not checksum. ;-)